# Could the amount of files in a windows directory impact the time it takes to copy new files into it?

Tags: windows, io

I have a export process that dumps new files into a folder on my Windows 7 PC each day (about 1-2K).  This directory is now unusably slow to navigate through Windows Explorer with millions of files in there now but my question is, should the amount of files in this directory impact the performance of simply copying new files into this same directory?

Answer (score 0):

The performance of simply copying files into the directory shouldn't be noticeably affected by the number of contained files, unless you start to reach tens of millions of them *or* you're talking about non-local drives.

You could try improving the navigating performance by running [contig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/contig) defragging tool on the folder periodically.